# Select strings by positions of words

Tags: python, string

For the following tuple

```
mysentence = 'i have a dog and a cat', 'i have a cat and a dog', 'i have a cat', 
             'i have a dog'
```

How to select only the strings 'i have a cat' , 'i have a dog', i.e exclude strings having the word `dog` or `cat` in the middle.

Comment: What with sentences like 'dog' or 'cat'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a Regular Expression to match the sentences you don't want.

We can build up the pattern as follows:

- We want to match dog or cat - `(dog|cat)`
- followed by a space, i.e. not at the end of the line

So our code looks like so:

```
>>> mysentence = ('i have a dog and a cat', 'i have a cat and a dog', 'i have a cat', 'i have a dog')
>>> import re                                                                   
>>> pattern = re.compile("(dog|cat) ")
>>> [x for x in mysentence if not pattern.search(x)]                            
['i have a cat', 'i have a dog']
```

Answer (score 4):

You can do this with regular expressions. The regex `.+(dog|cat).+` will match one or more characters, followed by dog or cat, and one of more characters afterwards. You can then use filter to find strings which don't match this regex:

```
import re
regex.compile(r'.+(dog|cat).+')
sentence = 'i have a dog and a cat', 'i have a cat and a dog', 'i have a cat', 
           'i have a dog'
filtered_sentence = filter(lambda s: not regex.match(s), sentence)
```

Answer (score 0):

If the string should just end with a specific phrase then this will do the job:

```
phases = ("I have a cat", "I have a dog")
for sentence in mysentence:
    for phase in phases:
        if sentence.lower().endswith(phase.lower()):
            print(sentence)
```

Comment: The OP wants to "exclude strings having the word dog or cat in the middle", so your answer would fail for e.g. `"You have a cat and I have a dog"`.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest thing that could possibly work:

```
In [10]: [phrase for phrase in mysentence if not ' and ' in phrase]
Out[10]: ['i have a cat', 'i have a dog']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use regexp or string methods.

I see other answered with regex, so I try string methods: with `string.find()` you will get position of substring in string. Then check if it is in the middle of the sentence.

```
def filter_function(sentence, words):
    for word in words:
        p = sentence.find(word)
        if p > 0 and p < len(sentence) - len(word):
            return 0
    return 1

for sentence in mysentence:
    print('%s: %d' % (sentence, filter_function(sentence, ['dog', 'cat'])))
```

You also must define what to do when you will have only 'cat' in sentence.

Answer (score 0):

```
for items in mysentence:
    if (items.find("dog")>=0)^(items.find("cat")>=0):
        print(items)
```

You just need an xor operator and the find function. No need to import